# What is the name of the elevator in the attached image?

Tags: word-request

I don't know what this elevator is called in English. I´m looking for images like this elevator in the real world

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it,but ***payload*** perhaps?

Comment: Which characteristics of the elevator are important? The shape? The size? What is the source of your picture? Many scenes only exist in the mind of who drew them.

Comment: I assume this type of elevator is called something in your native language. Have you tried using a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is a bit ambiguous, depending on the property you want to express.

- If you mean a lift that is intended to transport goods (as opposed to passengers), you see a **cargo/freight lift or elevator**.
- If you are focused on the fact that the lift works by pulling/pushing the platform or cabin along a slope (and not hanging freely on a wire or rope), you have an **inclined lift**.

And of course you can combine both purpose and technical method and get, for example, an **inclined freight lift**.

Comment: @jax I appreciate your thanks, but let me point you to our [tour] and [help], where you will learn a lot about the workings and rules of the site. One of them is that we typically don't write "thank you" comments. See the help for what we do instead: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers